# Is there a lax, permissive XML parser for PHP?

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm looking for a parser that will allow me to successfully parse broken xml, taking a "best guess" approach - for instance.

```
    <thingy>
       <description>
           something <b>with</b> bogus<br> 
           markup not wrapped in CDATA
       </description>
    </thingy>
```

Ideally, it will yield a thingy object, with a description property and whatever tag soup inside.

Other suggestions on how to attack the problem (other than having valid markup to start with) welcome.

Non-php solutions (Beautiful Soup (python) for instance) are not outside the pale, but I'd prefer to stick to the prevailing skill-set in the company

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't getting the point of XML: XML's main idea is that it will kill you, your family, your friends and anybody you have ever talked to, if it encounters a syntax error. XML without draconian error handling is just not XML anymore ^^

Comment: @nikic - I've been in the same position as the OP of having to deal with broken "XML" input supplied by a third party that didn't get the point of XML. While I agree it's not ideal, when the data has to be imported and we can't get the third party to fix their systems, we just have to deal with it.  :-(

Comment: Pretty much as @Spudley describes it, yeah

Comment: *(tip)* http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387

Comment: If it can successfully parse broken XML then it might be a very useful piece of software, but it's not an XML parser (conformant XML parsers aren't allowed to do that).

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.loadhtml) (or `DOMDocument::loadhtmlfile()`) to convert your broken XML to proper XML. If you don't like dealing with `DOMDocument` objectsThen use `saveXML()` and load the resulting XML string with SimpleXML.

```
$dom = DOMDocument::loadHTMLfile($filepath);
if (!$dom)
{
    throw new Exception("Could not load the lax XML file");
}
// Now you can work with your XML file using the $dom object.


// If you'd like using SimpleXML, do the following steps.
$xml = new SimpleXML($dom->saveXML());
unset($dom);
```

I've tried this script:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('badformatted.xml');
if (!$dom)
{
    die('error');
}
$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('description');
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++)
{
    echo "Node content: ".$nodes->item($i)->textContent."\n";
}
```

The output when executing this from the CLI:

```
carlos@marmolada:~/xml$ php test.php

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag thingy invalid in badformatted.xml, line: 1 in /home/carlos/xml/test.php on line 3

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag description invalid in badformatted.xml, line: 2 in /home/carlos/xml/test.php on line 3
Node content:
                something with bogus
                markup not wrapped in CDATA

carlos@marmolada:~/xml$
```

edit: some minor corrections and error treatment.

edit2: Change to non-static call to avoid E_STRICT error, added test case.

Comment: Alas, both fail - the XML one because of the borked XML, the HTML because of the 'invalid' (for HTML) element tags.

Comment: In a test I've done right now, it emits warnings about unknown html nodes, but it loads all elements (including these 'unknown' tags) correctly.

Comment: You, sir, are correct - though the warnings are a PITA, I can temporarily silence those for this particular task.

Comment: Just use the @ operator for that particular call: `@$dom->loadHTMLFile($file);`

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use the [Tidy HTML](http://tidy.sourceforge.net) library ([PHP binding here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php)) to clean the HTML first. That survives quite a lot of fairly hideous input, and I've seen people use it for scraping rather ropey HTML before.

Comment: That would be my advice. Pre-process and once it's well-formed, you simply do not validate it. I'm assuming that this is somebody's idea of an RSS webfeed?

Comment: Someone's idea of a product catalogue, even - oh well, Carlos' answer does it, though I'll probably follow on with an HTML tidy as you suggest... just to make sure the internal markup doesn't bork anything else.