# Regular expression backreference non-capturing group?

Tags: php, regex

Against a string like this:

```
<h3>title</h3>
<h4>title</h4>
```

How to match the tags correspondingly and get the text in them?

This works but it unnecessarily gets the tag name:

```
'@<(h[34])>(.+)</\1>@sU'
```

However this doesn't seem to work as I don't want to get the tag name but just want to backreference it:

```
'@<(?:h[34])>(.+)</\1>@sU'
```

I'm using PHP preg_match(). Why doesn't the 2nd approach work? Is it possible to back reference a non-capturing group?

Comment: No, you can't backreference something that isn't there. How would `/.+\7/` work? Your second examples `\1` would match the `(.+)` content.

Comment: @mario, so how does one match a HTML tag and the content in it using regex? Any common practice here?

Comment: You use a DOM parser and not regex

Comment: @hjpotter92, even for mal-formed DOM documents? I thought it's more universal to use regex so that I wouldn't freak out on broken DOM. Plus I may also need to parse something other than XML / HTML documents but ordinary strings with similar patterns.

Comment: @kavoir.com https://stackoverflow.com/q/6031546/1190388

Comment: [**Don't parse X/HTML with regex. Don't parse X/HTML with regex. Don't parse X/HTML with regex.**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) Did I mention not to parse X/HTML with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) could be used later on in the regular expression as a backreference to what was matched in that captured group. By placing `?:` inside you specify that the group is not to be captured, but to group expressions.

You can use the branch reset feature `(?| ... | ... )` that way you don't have your expression matching non-corresponding tags and both capturing groups in the alternatives are considered as one capturing group.

```
~(?|<h3>(.+?)</h3>|<h4>(.+?)</h4>)~s
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gB6kK2/1)

Comment: I didn't do that. Why **.+?** but not just **.+** ?

Comment: Because without the `U` modifier `.+` is greedy meaning if there are more than 1 tag it will continue to match.

Comment: So **.+?** is the ungreedy version of **.+**    ?

Comment: Does **~<(?:h[34])>(.+?)</(?:h[34])>~s** also match non-corresponding tags? Such as <h3>...</h4>?

Comment: Thanks for the update but it would be much better if we have a universal way to match HTML tags with regex. I can't believe it's so hard!

Comment: I guess then it's impossible to come up with a universal way for regex to match HTML tags without capturing the tag name?